# Retain f-string space padding when creating a dataframe from a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe initialized like below to give the structure

```
dummyDict = {('Summary', 'Value'):
       {'Row1': 'Sales',
        'Row2': 'Profit',
        'Row3': 'Escalation'},
     ('Summary', 'Conditions'):
        {'Row1': '-', 
        'Row2': '-',
        'Row3': '-',
        }}
```

This when printed returns

```
{('Summary', 'Value'): {'Row1': 'Sales',
  'Row2': 'Profit',
  'Row3': 'Escalation'},
 ('Summary', 'Conditions'): {'Row1': '-', 'Row2': '-', 'Row3': '-'}}
```

Now, I 'fill' the values like so

```
salesLimit = 1000
profitLimit = 35
escalationLimit = 5
dummyDict[('Summary', 'Conditions')]['Row1']= f'<{salesLimit : 6}'
dummyDict[('Summary', 'Conditions')]['Row2']= f'>{profitLimit : 6}'
dummyDict[('Summary', 'Conditions')]['Row3']= f'<{escalationLimit : 6}'
```

This when printed returns

```
{('Summary', 'Value'): {'Row1': 'Sales',
  'Row2': 'Profit',
  'Row3': 'Escalation'},
 ('Summary', 'Conditions'): {'Row1': '<  1000',
  'Row2': '>    35',
  'Row3': '<     5'}}
```

Here you can notice the the `space padding` using the f-string is just fine.

However, when I create a dataframe using `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(dummyDict)` or `pd.DataFrame(dummyDict)`, this string `space padding` is lost!

I get something like this

[image]

```
       Summary
        Value       Conditions
Row1    Sales          < 1000
Row2    Profit           > 35
Row3    Escalation       < 5
```

What I was expecting was something like this

```
       Summary
        Value       Conditions
Row1    Sales          < 1000
Row2    Profit         >   35
Row3    Escalation     <    5
```

Can you please let me know how to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is your pandas version?

Comment: My pandas version is 1.4.2

Comment: @moys My version is same, also working fine.

Comment: @SharimIqbal Hmm.. that is strange! I don't know why it is not working for me!

Comment: @moys can you try this code `print(len(f'{"Hello":10}'))` and tell me the output. Is it 10 or 5?

Comment: The length is printed as 10

Comment: What is `print (df[('Summary','Conditions')].tolist())` ? For me `['<  1000', '>    35', '<     5']`

Comment: Same for me also `['<  1000', '>    35', '<     5']` ! But it is displayed like I have shown in the Jupyter notebook. Has this something to do with  Jupyter notebook?

Comment: Since you mention Jupyter notebook, try this first for yourself on the command line. Either jupyter console, or just the standard Python prompt.

Comment: I exported the file to excel (which is my final goal) & there the `space padding` seems to be preserved.

Comment: Should I leave the question here (for someone else facing the same issue) or delete it?

Comment: @moys If you solve your problem, you can post the solution as answer.

Answer (score 0):

The reason the Pandas dataframe is not displayed correctly (i.e with Padding) in Jupyter notebook is because Jupyter notebook displays the pandas dataframe as HTML & in HTML
**multiple consecutive spaces as treated as a single space**.

To overcome this behavior you can use `df.style.set_properties(**{'white-space': 'pre'})`.
The styled df will display the df with spaces as desired.